# Bootstrap tab Active/inactive and Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm using the Angularjs and Bootstrap tab here my code:

```
  <body  ng-controller="TabsCtrl">
    <button ng-click="addNewWorkspace('jobs')">Open Tab jobs<i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></button> 
    <button ng-click="addNewWorkspace('invoices')">Open Tab invoices<i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></button> 
    <button ng-click="addNewWorkspace('payments')">Open Tab payments<i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></button> 

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li ng-class="tabClass(tab)" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" tab="tab">
        <a href="{{tab.link}}" ng-click="setSelectedTab(tab)">{{tab.label}}
        <button ng-click="removeTab($index)">-<i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-view></div>

  </body>
```

When I press any button, it will open a new tab, here my first problem, the tab is created but not active, I need press the tab created to see the info.

My second problem is when I open any the tab, and is closed, the tab does not show the info about other tab open. For example: I open payments and open this tab, when I close it not show the jobs info.

What I did?

I tried use `$location.path` when I add/remove a workspace to force that shows any other tab but that does not work. Also I tried `$window` with the same result.

I don't know if I confused the concepts here.

[Live Demo With complete code](http://plnkr.co/edit/7XDVslw78DCO1Xi22WMM?p=preview)

Comment: Are you expecting a new tab each time you click  'Open tab xxx' buttons ? or what you want is just have 3 tabs all the time ?

Comment: I'm expecting open a new tab when any 'open tab button' is pressed, and the tab open need be active. Now I open/close tabs but I'm not figure out about active tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.addNewWorkspace = function(page) {
var tab = {
    link: '#/' + page,
    label: page
};
$scope.tabs.push(tab);
$scope.selectedTab = tab;
$location.path('/' + tab.label);
};
```

choose the current tab as selectedTab

```
$scope.selectedTab=tab;
```

redirect to new location

```
$location.path('/'+tab.label);
```

Comment: + 1 although not resolve all my problem but is a concept problem.Now When I try to close a tab open, that redirect me to the same tab becouse the ul-li structure, I need update that. If you see when you click the 'X' in the tab it redirects me to the same tab open.

Comment: the ui-li structure is fixed with `ng-click="removeTab($index);$event.preventDefault(); $event.stopPropagation();"`